# java gc 100% of from and 0% of to space

Tags: java, garbage-collection

get a strange problem, the From space is 100% and to space is always 0.
anyone can help me get out of here?

jdk **1.8.25**
os: **linux**

get the following with JMAP

```
Heap Configuration:
   MinHeapFreeRatio         = 40
   MaxHeapFreeRatio         = 70
   MaxHeapSize              = 32212254720 (30720.0MB)
   NewSize                  = 268435456 (256.0MB)
   MaxNewSize               = 268435456 (256.0MB)
   OldSize                  = 31943819264 (30464.0MB)
   NewRatio                 = 5
   SurvivorRatio            = 4
   MetaspaceSize            = 268435456 (256.0MB)
   CompressedClassSpaceSize = 1073741824 (1024.0MB)
   MaxMetaspaceSize         = 268435456 (256.0MB)
   G1HeapRegionSize         = 0 (0.0MB)

Heap Usage:
    New Generation (Eden + 1 Survivor Space):
   capacity = 223739904 (213.375MB)
   used     = 113230096 (107.98463439941406MB)
   free     = 110509808 (105.39036560058594MB)
   50.607913016714264% used
Eden Space:
   capacity = 179044352 (170.75MB)
   used     = 68534544 (65.35963439941406MB)
   free     = 110509808 (105.39036560058594MB)
   38.27797036568906% used
From Space:
   capacity = 44695552 (42.625MB)
   used     = 44695552 (42.625MB)
   free     = 0 (0.0MB)
   100.0% used
To Space:
   capacity = 44695552 (42.625MB)
   used     = 0 (0.0MB)
   free     = 44695552 (42.625MB)
   0.0% used
concurrent mark-sweep generation:
   capacity = 31943819264 (30464.0MB)
   used     = 390280592 (372.20057678222656MB)
   free     = 31553538672 (30091.799423217773MB)
   1.2217718513072038% used
```

in gc.log, it always say 'allocation failure', how can i change the 'survivor size'?

```
[GC (Allocation Failure) 10.371: [ParNew Desired survivor size 22347776 bytes, new threshold 15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Allocation failure" is normal cause of minor GC (older JVM were not printing cause, but it always has been allocation failure).

"To space" should always be empty (it is not empty, during Stop-the-World GC phase, but then GC is finished it is always 0%).

100% "From space" may be ok too. Normally JVM adjust tenuring threshold to keep "From space" as close to 100% as possible. Though, having it exactly at 100% means premature promotion for some objects.

Size of survival space is controlled by `-XX:SurvivorRatio=N` option. Using `-XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution` is useful for tuning young GC.

[Here](http://blog.ragozin.info/2013/11/hotspot-jvm-garbage-collection-options.html) can find more JVM options related to GC tuning.

Comment: thanks! will try   -XX:SurvivorRatio=N and  XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution

Comment: @StephenC all young collectors (including G1) in HotSpot JVM are Stop the World (i.e. not concurrent)